# Java - Fullscreen and windowed mode

Tags: java, jframe, fullscreen, draw, windowed

Is it possible that if i switch between the two modes and draw things to adjust them so that in windowed mode the things seem to be drawn as in the fullscreen mode but are actually smaller...

So that's my code:

Constructor:
GraphicsEnvironment gfxEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

GraphicsDevice gfxDevice = gfxEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice();

private boolean fullscreen = true; // not really like that

if(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

```
        setUndecorated(true);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        DisplayMode getMode = gfxDevice.getDisplayMode();
        DisplayMode displayMode = new DisplayMode(getMode.getWidth(), getMode.getHeight(), getMode.getBitDepth(), getMode.getRefreshRate());
        gfxDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Frame.this);
        gfxDevice.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        fullscreen = true;
    } else {
        setUndecorated(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        fullscreen = false;
    }
```

Switch the screens: if(fullscreen) {

```
        dispose();
        setUndecorated(false);
        gfxDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        fullscreen = false;
    } else {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        setUndecorated(true);
        gfxDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Frame.this);
        fullscreen = true;
    }
```

draw: private void draw(Graphics g) {

```
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 800);
}
```

So how can I adjust the Rect?
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can base the drawing of the rect on the screen size. So base it off of a fraction of the window width and height with `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width;` and `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;`
instead of fixed pixel values.

Comment: And how can I draw exactly that rect: (50, 30, 200, 350) if my fullscreen size is 1600 and 900 and my window mode size is 800 and 600? :)

Comment: Oh I just divided the x coordinate and width of the rect with 2 and the y - coordinates with 1.5(I think) so i took that code:      float strechX = 1.0f, strechY = 1.0f;
        if(!fullscreen) {
            strechX = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width / WIDTH;
            strechY = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height / HEIGHT;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect((int) (0.0f / strechX), (int) (0.0f / strechY), (int) (100.0f / strechX), (int) (200.0f / strechY));

Comment: It's really hard to read that in a comment but did it work? If so, then good work! It's important to always scale view size to screen/window size. It makes the code tedious but it produces consistent results.